# Java - PDFBox - How can I add new page if the content of my text exceeds the first page of the PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

My project requires printing of PDF documents.

I created a void method that creates page on a pdf document that I'm printing.

```
public void createPage(){
        PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
        document.addPage( blankPage );
}
```

Whenever I'm calling the method, it creates new page from the PDF. Upon filling
contents to page that I've created, some part of the text (from the loops which comes from the database) are not showing (cause I guess it exceeds the first page size that I created). I want it to proceed to the second page whenever it will going to exceed the size of the page. I've tried several solutions from my research such as adding a parameter to the class constructor:

```
public void createPage(){
        PDPage blankPage = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);

        document.addPage( blankPage );
}
```

but adding the parameter on the construction is not working because there is no constant property named PAGE_SIZE_LETTER to PDPage class that I'm using.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: What is your actual problem? If the first `createPage` variant properly adds a page to your document, use it instead of the second one. From your description it appears as if page *creation* is not your issue at all, most likely your *switching output* to the second page is. But as you do not show how you end printing to the first page and start printing to the second one, it's difficult to help in any concise manner.

Comment: In PDFBox 2.0.*, use `PDRectangle.LETTER`, or `PDRectangle.A4` or whatever you want. A4 is the default. LETTER is smaller than A4. The correct page size depends on what country you work for. AFAIK most of the world uses A4, only the US uses LETTER. So you'll have to adjust your logic to work on several pages, i.e. reposition on top.